# Renaming a *txt file based on the content of the *txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have read all the similar questions and tried to use it to make a batch script, but unsuccessfully.

I have several *txt files, which are containing information within the file, which should be stored in the file name.

E.g. the *txt below, I would like to store the date from the first line (20171115) and the number in the back of the file (905707) in the file name.

[image: *txt file]

In this case, the file name should be "20171115_BOM_905707.txt"

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is it you're actually stuck on?  Getting a list of files, reading text from a file, parsing that text, or renaming the file?  And you've applied the tag 'batch-file' - is that a requirement?

Comment: See `For /?` which does many things, one is to process a text file line by line.

Comment: I have a build a script (.bat file) which is combining several files and renaming them based on the current date and a static description (it works also). But this is not good enough. It is required that I go into the files and read the content and bring it back to the file name.

Comment: Helping implies that you tried something on your own, so please share your efforts and precisely describe where you are stuck! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "dir_with_files=C:\files"
for %%# in ("%dir_with_files%\*") do (
  set "date_="
  set "number="
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3,4,5,6 delims=. " %%a in ("%%#") do (
     if not defined date_ (
      set "date_=%%a%%b%%c"
      set "number=%%d"
     )
  )
  ren "%%~f#" "!date_!_BOM_!number!%%~x#"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: suboptimal solution, your script is reading the full text file when just the first line is needed.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Additional question to this script. During the process of combining *txt files, I give the file already a specific name (e.g. "X_BOM_X). Can the script only take the file which is named this way?

Comment: @Jake - yes . In the first for lool - `for %%# in ("%dir_with_files%\*")` you can whatever filter you want - e.g. `for %%# in ("%dir_with_files%\*_BOM_*")`

Comment: @PA. - depends how big the files are. Calling non-internal command like `FIND` or `MORE` will also decrease the performance.Also `goto` or `call` as it will parse the entire script.If the file is only 6 lines long (assuming that from the screenshot provided) probably in this way it will be faster

Comment: yep, totally agree, it depens on how big files are, which you don't know in advance. What you know in advance is that you just need one line. So, read just that one and you will always be safe. It's very easy, just add a goto.

Comment: @PA.  - I'll need also a subroutine - because I have two nested for loops and `GOTO` will break the outer for loop context. Using both `goto` and `call` will definetely slow down the script.Rather will be beter to use MORE

Comment: @npocmaka! Works perfectly! Thanks so much! One last question - "How do I always delete the last line of my *txt file?

Comment: Apparently raptors are spreading fire in Australia. Are you on a BOM website that tracks fire spreading raptors? Don't get scared, they're not veloraptors (although dogs go missing in Newtown I see the posters). See https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40375/are-raptors-in-australia-intentionally-spreading-brush-fires-to-smoke-out-prey

Comment: @Jake - it is not so simple in pure batch. It is easier with powershell . May it will be better to ask a new question